# Using the django authentication system

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, authentication, django-views

I want to login with **handler**.

I have a code use **session** but i want to use **handler**:

I have visit :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/

But i don't understand complete.

I want to log user (with username or email and password)

Do you have a code for example or project in **stackoverflow** or **github** or . . . ???

Comment: what you don't understand and what exactly do you want from auth

Comment: I want to log use.i don't understand loger!

Comment: what's a loger?

Comment: I dont understand how it work!where should i import?!

Comment: log user means you want to create a log file and login means something else. I don't understand if you are saying log the user or login the user?

Comment: I want a project to explan for me.to understand more and use it well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147476/discussion-between-arpit-solanki-and-snip1377).

Comment: Login user .(for example like set session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login the user is easy if you are using default user model from `django.contrib.auth.models`

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
def user_login(request):
    # check here that request.method is POST or not.
    user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get('username'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # send some http response here that login successful or redirect to some other page

    else:
        # return an error page saying that username password not correct
```

authenticate function will check for username and password in User table in the database if it founds a user matching query then it returns the user object else it will return None. You might not want to manage sessions as django already sets a cookie for every user that successfully logs in so if user has logged in once then he will not be required to enter password again.

Comment: It will not set session?just return user's object?

Comment: it won't return username and password. session is set in request object and when you send any response from django after login it will set session in the browser

Comment: Tnx a lot.when i use this answer.i will accept and vote up it.(now i am with phone)